# Does association in UML associate objects or classes?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, relationships

On Wikipedia, I'm reading that an association relationship is an instance level relationship so we are talking about the relationship between the objects of two classes.

When we actually draw a class diagram, why do we use association on the class elements or blocks rather than objects? And there are also class level relationships for which we again use class elements. Since we don't have any way to show if we are talking about objects or classes I find this confusing. For example: I've heard people saying "Associate these two classes" Doesn't that sound wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`Links` are to `Associations` as `Objects` are to `Classes`.

A Class is an abstraction that describes many specific objects.  Similarly, an Association is an abstraction that describes many links between objects.

So your statement

> an association relationship is an instance level relationship

isn't strictly correct because it mixes the abstraction (Association Relationship) with the instances it represents.

hth.

Comment: Hi @sfinnie ! Your answer is very useful,thank you very much and hope to you the best

Answer (score 3):

In fact, when you associate two or more classes it is done thanks to two or more UML Properties.
These latter are the "ends" of your associations and are "instance" i.e. they are typed by classe.
So an association is created between two classes on a class diagram but between each classes and the association you have a UML property.

Hoping it sounds clear ...

Answer (score 1):

When you are making a class diagram you are defining types. Suppose you have a class *User* and a class *Account*, you use an association between *User* and *Account* to say: *User* instances can have link(s) with *Account* instances at runtime.

So, you use classes and associations at type level (class diagram) to define what can be possible at runtime (instance level).

Answer (score 0):

The object is actually the Class that has been created virtualy. So a class is the "static" version of an Object. So, when we speak of UML, we speak about classes and not object.

But correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: There are UML diagrams that deal with instances/objects too. So, yes, your statement `"So, when we speak of UML, we speak about classes and not object"` is wrong.